# Macro (dnaseq) inside table

Tags: tables, formatting

Is it possible to format text inside a table using a macro? I naively tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\begin{document}

\section{Working}

\DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA !

\section{Failing}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
 Sequence 1 & \DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA !
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But the \DNA command does not work inside a table. I am getting a

> Missing } inserted.

and multiple

> Undefined control sequence.

errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macros get confused for the fact that `tabular` cells are typeset in restricted horizontal mode, where line breaks are not possible.

However, even specifying `p{<length>}` doesn't really work.

You can use a workaround with a `minipage`. In order to compute a suitable width, I set `\ttfamily` before the `minipage` and set the width to 24.1em.

Why? The `\DNA` construction uses `\ttfamily` and each block lists 10 nucleotides. So we have 5em for every block; you also need to consider 2em for the numbers (four digits) and 0.5em for each space between the columns. So four blocks per line requires space for 48 characters each 0.5em wide. However it turns out that the macro needs some room for manoeuvering, and a surplus 0.1em seems to take to a happy end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\begin{document}

\section{Working}

\DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGT%
CATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA%
ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCAT%
CGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAG%
TCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGT%
AACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA !

\section{Failing}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
Sequence 1 & 
\ttfamily\begin{minipage}[t]{24.1em}
  \DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTA%
         GTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATG%
         CATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGT%
         ATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAA%
         CGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAG%
         TCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGC%
         ATCGTATGTA !
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Verbatim environments in tabular give problem (see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220121/verbatim-environment-inside-latex-cell).

I would suggest using a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\begin{document}

\section{Working}

\DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA !

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\begin{minipage}{.75\linewidth}
\DNA!  ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTA !
\end{minipage}}

\section{Working with a box}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
 Sequence 1 & \usebox{\mybox}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]