# How to set a minipage (or any environment) around column elements?

Tags: tables, minipage, columns

I've come across a problem that's bugging me.
I have a table where I need to put all elements from the second column in a minipage. I've started to do that manually for every row and then realized, that I can propably just use the `>` and `<` operators in the column definition to do that, like:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l>{\begin{minipage}[t]{24.1em}}l>{\end{minipage}}
    ...
\end{tabular}
```

Unfortunatelly, that doesn't work and I get errors about a closing curly bracket after `\begin{minipage}`.
I have tried it with the centering environment and it doesn't work either.

Is there a way to put environments around column elements like that or is there something like a `\minipage`-command, like `\center` is to `\begin{centering}...\end{centering}`?

Thanks :-)

---

Note: The minipage is used for the a `\DNA! ... !` command from the `dnaseq` package (which would also be put in the column definition, but that shouldn't be a problem and is, to my knowledge, needed for it to work inside a cell. However if someone has an idea how to use it in a cell without a minipage I'd also be happy to hear it.

### Edit

Changing the column type from `l` to `p` doesn't work, I believe it to be the same issue as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594561/macro-dnaseq-inside-table) on which I have hased my code on.
Here is an example of my whole code currently in use where I'd like to put the commands from the second column into the column specification with the `>` and `<`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, dnaseq}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
    \toprule
    \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Sequence} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\small\emph{Continued}} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Sequence} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    1 & \ttfamily\footnotesize\begin{minipage}[t]{24.1em}\DNA! ATGACCATGATTACGGATTCACTGGCCGTCGTTTTACAACGTCGTGACTGGGAAAACCCTGGCGTTACCCAACTTAATCGCCTTGCAGCACATCCCCCTTTCGCCAGCTGGCGTAATAGCGAAGAGGCCCGCACCGATCGCCCTTCCCAACAGTTGCGCAGCCTGAATGGCGAATGGCGCTTTGCCTGGTTTCCGGCACCAGAAGCGGTGCCGGAAAGCTGGCTGGAGTGCGATCTTCCTGAGGCCGATACTGTCGTCGTCCCCTCAAACTGGCAGATGCACGGTTACGATGCGCCCATCTACACCAACGTGACCTATCCCATTACGGTCAATCCGCCGTTTGTTCCCACGGAGAATCCGACGGGTTGTTACTCGCTCACATTTAATGTTGATGAAAGCTGGCTACAGGAAGGCCAGACGCGAATTATTTTTGATGGCGTTAACTCGGCGTTTCATCTGTGGTGCAACGGGCGCTGGGTCGGTTACGGCCAGGACAGTCGTTTGCCGTCTGAATTTGACCTGAGCGCATTTTTACGCGCCGGAGAAAACCGCCTCGCGGTGATGGTGCTGCGCTGGAGTGACGGCAGTTATCTGGAAGATCAGGATATGTGGCGGATGAGCGGCATTTTCCGTGACGTCTCGTTGCTGCA ! \end{minipage} \\
    \midrule
    2 & \ttfamily\footnotesize\begin{minipage}[t]{24.1em}\DNA! TAAACCGACTACACAAATCAGCGATTTCCATGTTGCCACTCGCTTTAATGATGATTTCAGCCGCGCTGTACTGGAGGCTGAAGTTCAGATGTGCGGCGAGTTGCGTGACTACCTACGGGTAACAGTTTCTTTATGGCAGGGTGAAACGCAGGTCGCCAGCGGCACCGCGCCTTTCGGCGGTGAAATTATCGATGAGCGTGGTGGTTATGCCGATCGCGTCACACTACGTCTGAACGTCGAAAACCCGAAACTGTGGAGCGCCGAAATCCCGAATCTCTATCGTGCGGTGGTTGAACTGCACACCGCCGACGGCACGCTGATTGAAGCAGAAGCCTGCGATGTCGGTTTCCGCGAGGTGCGGATTGAAAATGGTCTGCTGCTGCTGAACGGCAAGCCGTTGCTGATTCGAGGCGTTAACCGTCACGAGCATCATCCTCTGCATGGTCAGGTCATGGATGAGCAGACGATGGTGCAGGATATCCTGCTGATGAAGCAGAACAACTTTAACGCCGTGCGCTGTTCGCATTATCCGAACCATCCGCTGTGGTACACGCTGTGCGACCGCTACGGCCTGTATGTGGTGGATGAAGCCAATATTGAAACCCACGGCATGGTGCCAATGAATCGTCTGACCGATGATCCGCGCTGGCTACCGGCGATGAGCGAACGCGTAACGCGAATGGTGCAG ! \end{minipage} \\
    \midrule
    3 & \ttfamily\footnotesize\begin{minipage}[t]{24.1em}\DNA! CGCGATCGTAATCACCCGAGTGTGATCATCTGGTCGCTGGGGAATGAATCAGGCCACGGCGCTAATCACGACGCGCTGTATCGCTGGATCAAATCTGTCGATCCTTCCCGCCCGGTGCAGTATGAAGGCGGCGGAGCCGACACCACGGCCACCGATATTATTTGCCCGATGTACGCGCGCGTGGATGAAGACCAGCCCTTCCCGGCTGTGCCGAAATGGTCCATCAAAAAATGGCTTTCGCTACCTGGAGAGACGCGCCCGCTGATCCTTTGCGAATACGCCCACGCGATGGGTAACAGTCTTGGCGGTTTCGCTAAATACTGGCAGGCGTTTCGTCAGTATCCCCGTTTACAGGGCGGCTTCGTCTGGGACTGGGTGGATCAGTCGCTGATTAAATATGATGAAAACGGCAACCCGTGGTCGGCTTACGGCGGTGATTTTGGCGATACGCCGAACGATCGCCAGTTCTGTATGAACGGTCTGGTCTTTGCCGACCGCACGCCGCATCCAGCGCTGACGGAAGCAAAACACCAGCAGCAGTTTTTCCAGTTCCGTTTATCCGGGCAAACCATCGAAGTGACCAGCGAATACCTGTTCCGTCATAGCGATAACGAGCTCCTGCACTGGATGGTGGCGCTGGATGGTAAGCCGCTGGCAAGCGGTGAAGTGCCTCTGGATGTCGCTCCACAAGGTAAACAGTTGATTGAACTGCCTGAACTACCGCAGCCGGAGAGCGCCGGGCAACTCTGGCTCACAGTACGCGTAGTGCAACCGAACGCGACCGCATGGTCAGAAGCCGGGCACATCAGCGCCTGGCAGCAGTGGCGTCTGGCGGAAAACCTCAGTGTGACGCTCCCCGCCGCGTCCCACGCCATCCCGCATCTGACCACCAGCGAAATGGATTTTTGCATCGAGCTGGGTAATAAGCGTTGGCAATTTAACCGCCAGTCAGGCTTTCTTTCACAGATGTGGATTGGCGATAAAAAACAACTGCTGACGCCGCTGCGCGATCAGTTCACCCGTGCACCGCTGGATAACGACATTGGCGTAAGTGAAGCGACCCGCATTGACCCTAACGCCTGGGTCGAACGCTGGAAGGCGGCGGGCCATTACCAGGCCGAAGCAGCGTTGTTGCAGTGCACGGCAGATACACTTGCTGATGCGGTGCTGATTACGACCGCTCACGCGTGGCAGCATCAGGGGAAAACCTTATTTATCAGCCGGAAAACCTACCGGATTGATGGTAGTGGTCAAATGGCGATTACCGTTGATGTTGAAGTGGCGAGCGATACACCGCATCCGGCGCGGATTGGCCTGAACTGCCAGCTGGCGCAGGTAGCAGAGCGGGTAAACTGGCTCGGATTAGGGCCGCAAGAAAACTATCCCGACCGCCTTACTGCCGCCTGTTTTGACCGCTGGGATCTGCCATTGTCAGACATGTATACCCCGTACGTCTTCCCGA ! \end{minipage}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `p` column type also work? It basically creates a `\parbox` inside the cell, which might already be enough for your needs.

Comment: try  Instead `tabular` use `tabularx` and define columns as `{ l X }`, Column `X` has features of ˛parbox with width calculated by LateX, In it you can use commands defined in the `dnaseq` packages on the same way as in the `minipage`. For more help please provide an example of small document with your table.

Comment: @JasperHabicht That doesn't work. I believe it to be the same problem as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594561/macro-dnaseq-inside-table), on which I have based my code on.

Comment: @Zarko `tabularx` doesn't seem to work with `\DNA! ... !`. Also, I forgot to clarify, I'm using a `longtable` as it will stretch over multiple pages

Comment: a `p` colum is a parbox which shares 99% of the code of minipage, I wonder what egreg was refering to, there are some edge cases where a minipage makes a difference but it seems surprising here.

Comment: You should really put an example using `\DNA!` in the question as changing `l` to `p{50pt}` is the generic answer, perhaps not valid due to some specific weirdness in that command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just updated the question. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: The entire answer is just about  features of  `\DNA` :-)

Answer (score 1):

a `minipage` is almost the same as a `\parbox` which is almost the same as a `p` column.

Unfortuately `\DNA` despite being a very small macro manages to hit most of the edge cases where there are differences. It assumes the line breaking width is `\textwidth` (which is false in lists or boxes etc, but `minipage` does re-set this locally). It  also locally inserts `\\`  to force line breaking assuming `\\`  won't have another definition, such as ending a table row.

Here I reset `\textwidth` and use `\raggdright` to add some glue and reset `\\`  so use `\tabularnewline` for table rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable, array,booktabs, dnaseq}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l>{\footnotesize\textwidth=\hsize\raggedright\endgraf\vspace{-\baselineskip}}p{250pt}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{No.} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Sequence}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\small\emph{Continued}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \textbf{No.} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Sequence}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    1 & \DNA! ATGACCATGATTACGGATTCACTGGCCGTCGTTTTACAACGTCGTGACTGGGAAAACCCTGGCGTTACCCAACTTAATCGCCTTGCAGCACATCCCCCTTTCGCCAGCTGGCGTAATAGCGAAGAGGCCCGCACCGATCGCCCTTCCCAACAGTTGCGCAGCCTGAATGGCGAATGGCGCTTTGCCTGGTTTCCGGCACCAGAAGCGGTGCCGGAAAGCTGGCTGGAGTGCGATCTTCCTGAGGCCGATACTGTCGTCGTCCCCTCAAACTGGCAGATGCACGGTTACGATGCGCCCATCTACACCAACGTGACCTATCCCATTACGGTCAATCCGCCGTTTGTTCCCACGGAGAATCCGACGGGTTGTTACTCGCTCACATTTAATGTTGATGAAAGCTGGCTACAGGAAGGCCAGACGCGAATTATTTTTGATGGCGTTAACTCGGCGTTTCATCTGTGGTGCAACGGGCGCTGGGTCGGTTACGGCCAGGACAGTCGTTTGCCGTCTGAATTTGACCTGAGCGCATTTTTACGCGCCGGAGAAAACCGCCTCGCGGTGATGGTGCTGCGCTGGAGTGACGGCAGTTATCTGGAAGATCAGGATATGTGGCGGATGAGCGGCATTTTCCGTGACGTCTCGTTGCTGCA !
 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    2 & \DNA! TAAACCGACTACACAAATCAGCGATTTCCATGTTGCCACTCGCTTTAATGATGATTTCAGCCGCGCTGTACTGGAGGCTGAAGTTCAGATGTGCGGCGAGTTGCGTGACTACCTACGGGTAACAGTTTCTTTATGGCAGGGTGAAACGCAGGTCGCCAGCGGCACCGCGCCTTTCGGCGGTGAAATTATCGATGAGCGTGGTGGTTATGCCGATCGCGTCACACTACGTCTGAACGTCGAAAACCCGAAACTGTGGAGCGCCGAAATCCCGAATCTCTATCGTGCGGTGGTTGAACTGCACACCGCCGACGGCACGCTGATTGAAGCAGAAGCCTGCGATGTCGGTTTCCGCGAGGTGCGGATTGAAAATGGTCTGCTGCTGCTGAACGGCAAGCCGTTGCTGATTCGAGGCGTTAACCGTCACGAGCATCATCCTCTGCATGGTCAGGTCATGGATGAGCAGACGATGGTGCAGGATATCCTGCTGATGAAGCAGAACAACTTTAACGCCGTGCGCTGTTCGCATTATCCGAACCATCCGCTGTGGTACACGCTGTGCGACCGCTACGGCCTGTATGTGGTGGATGAAGCCAATATTGAAACCCACGGCATGGTGCCAATGAATCGTCTGACCGATGATCCGCGCTGGCTACCGGCGATGAGCGAACGCGTAACGCGAATGGTGCAG !
\tabularnewline
    \midrule
    3 & \DNA! CGCGATCGTAATCACCCGAGTGTGATCATCTGGTCGCTGGGGAATGAATCAGGCCACGGCGCTAATCACGACGCGCTGTATCGCTGGATCAAATCTGTCGATCCTTCCCGCCCGGTGCAGTATGAAGGCGGCGGAGCCGACACCACGGCCACCGATATTATTTGCCCGATGTACGCGCGCGTGGATGAAGACCAGCCCTTCCCGGCTGTGCCGAAATGGTCCATCAAAAAATGGCTTTCGCTACCTGGAGAGACGCGCCCGCTGATCCTTTGCGAATACGCCCACGCGATGGGTAACAGTCTTGGCGGTTTCGCTAAATACTGGCAGGCGTTTCGTCAGTATCCCCGTTTACAGGGCGGCTTCGTCTGGGACTGGGTGGATCAGTCGCTGATTAAATATGATGAAAACGGCAACCCGTGGTCGGCTTACGGCGGTGATTTTGGCGATACGCCGAACGATCGCCAGTTCTGTATGAACGGTCTGGTCTTTGCCGACCGCACGCCGCATCCAGCGCTGACGGAAGCAAAACACCAGCAGCAGTTTTTCCAGTTCCGTTTATCCGGGCAAACCATCGAAGTGACCAGCGAATACCTGTTCCGTCATAGCGATAACGAGCTCCTGCACTGGATGGTGGCGCTGGATGGTAAGCCGCTGGCAAGCGGTGAAGTGCCTCTGGATGTCGCTCCACAAGGTAAACAGTTGATTGAACTGCCTGAACTACCGCAGCCGGAGAGCGCCGGGCAACTCTGGCTCACAGTACGCGTAGTGCAACCGAACGCGACCGCATGGTCAGAAGCCGGGCACATCAGCGCCTGGCAGCAGTGGCGTCTGGCGGAAAACCTCAGTGTGACGCTCCCCGCCGCGTCCCACGCCATCCCGCATCTGACCACCAGCGAAATGGATTTTTGCATCGAGCTGGGTAATAAGCGTTGGCAATTTAACCGCCAGTCAGGCTTTCTTTCACAGATGTGGATTGGCGATAAAAAACAACTGCTGACGCCGCTGCGCGATCAGTTCACCCGTGCACCGCTGGATAACGACATTGGCGTAAGTGAAGCGACCCGCATTGACCCTAACGCCTGGGTCGAACGCTGGAAGGCGGCGGGCCATTACCAGGCCGAAGCAGCGTTGTTGCAGTGCACGGCAGATACACTTGCTGATGCGGTGCTGATTACGACCGCTCACGCGTGGCAGCATCAGGGGAAAACCTTATTTATCAGCCGGAAAACCTACCGGATTGATGGTAGTGGTCAAATGGCGATTACCGTTGATGTTGAAGTGGCGAGCGATACACCGCATCCGGCGCGGATTGGCCTGAACTGCCAGCTGGCGCAGGTAGCAGAGCGGGTAAACTGGCTCGGATTAGGGCCGCAAGAAAACTATCCCGACCGCCTTACTGCCGCCTGTTTTGACCGCTGGGATCTGCCATTGTCAGACATGTATACCCCGTACGTCTTCCCGA !

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```